# Media player doesn't show songs

Tags: external-sd, 4.3-jelly-bean, files, media-player, media-files

I have a ZTE Whirl 2 (a.k.a. Z667G or Salem 2). I'm running Android 4.3 Jelly Bean.

Whenever I start my media player (I use Black Player EX, but it happens with all media players, and the default file explorer) after a reboot or USB connection, my songs will not show up:
[image: Not working 1]
[image: Not working 2]

I have no idea why this is. The songs will not show up unless I restart the application several times. Anyone have any idea why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are the songs in local storage or on the SD card? If they're on the SD card, the time it takes to mount the SD card after a reboot could explain your issue. If the songs are stored locally, it's probably just the time it takes to populate your stored data.

Comment: @owlswipe The songs are in external storage, but I can access them with ES File Explorer long before the media player loads.

Comment: "unless I restart the application several times" - if you have a very large library, the Media Storage is probably re-scanning during that period, thus the library is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: @AndyYan You know, that very well may be the problem. I obligate you to add that as an answer; if the community seems to receive it well, and no better solutions show up, I'll accept it within 48 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Note this part in your description:

> ...The songs will not show up unless I restart the application several times...

Every reboot or finished USB connection will broadcast a `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` intent to apps. Media Storage captures this...

[image]

...and triggers a re-scan of the media library. If you have a very large one, the Media Storage is probably re-scanning during that period (could take minutes, depending on your phone's specs), thus the library is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Could you please add credible sources to back your claim? Your argument may very well be the thing happening in the device, but unless proven technically it is hypothesis.

Comment: @Firelord Edited to include a bit more details. Apart from that, best I could do is get some screenshots of Media Storage process running after a USB connection - it happens so naturally I don't know what backing I need.

Comment: I was only concerned with this: *the Media Storage is probably re-scanning during that period*, hence I asked for source(s). Rest is something I'm aware of.

Comment: @Firelord Gotcha, so I think I do need screenshot or video on that. I'll see if it's possible.